# Pusher ruby library - HttpClient::KeepAliveDisconnected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httpclient, pusher

I have a sidekiq job that is triggering events. I installed `pusher-http-ruby` onto Rails. I'm sending a request to Slanger on localhost. During testing, using `pusher-fake`, Webmock is happy that the requests are being sent. However, in development (and presumably in production, not that I've deployed) I get...

```
HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected:
snip/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:808:in `block in parse_header'"
snip/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:808:in `block in parse_header'",
snip/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:88:in `block in timeout'",
snip/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:98:in `call'",
snip/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:98:in `timeout'",
snip/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:801:in `parse_header'",
snip/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:784:in `read_header'",
snip/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient/session.rb:561:in `get_header'",
snip/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1299:in `do_get_header'",
snip/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1245:in `do_get_block'",
snip/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1019:in `block in do_request'",
snip/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1138:in `rescue in protect_keep_alive_disconnected'",
snip/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1132:in `protect_keep_alive_disconnected'",
snip/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:1014:in `do_request'",
snip/gems/httpclient-2.8.3/lib/httpclient.rb:856:in `request'",
snip/gems/pusher-1.3.0/lib/pusher/request.rb:30:in `send_sync'",
snip/gems/pusher-1.3.0/lib/pusher/resource.rb:18:in `post'",
snip/gems/pusher-1.3.0/lib/pusher/client.rb:177:in `post'",
snip/gems/pusher-1.3.0/lib/pusher/client.rb:277:in `trigger'"
```

I've tried it inside and outside of Sidekiq with the same result. It never gets to Slanger - just dies in rails without leaving. Can someone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was sending a request to the websocket. I'd set the pusher port to that of the websocket rather than of the API server. Oops. Sorted now!